# link dependiendo del radio button seleccionado en PHP y HTML

Tags: javascript, html5

hola a todos quisiera saber la forma de hacer un link dependiendo el radio button seleccionado

```html
<section id="form">
    <form action="votarEncuesta.php" class="contact_form" name="form1" method="post">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td width="50"><input  type="radio" id="Choice1" name="seccion" value="Encuestas"></br></td>  
                <td width="470">Encuestas</td>
            </tr> 
            <tr>
                <td width="50"><input type="radio" id="Choice2" name="seccion" value="Preguntas"></br></td>  
                <td width="470">Preguntas</td>
            </tr> 
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <input type="submit" class="submit" value="Ver" />
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </form>
</section>
```

Comment: El formulario parece correcto, deberías publicar el fichero votarEncuesta.php o parte de éste en dónde realizas las asignación de las variables pasadas por POST, ya que parece que el problema está ahí.

Comment: pero yo lo que busco es que al seleccionar el radio button de encuestas y dar clic en el boton ver me mande a encuestas.php y si seleccionan el radio button de preguntas y al dar clic en el boton ver me mande a preguntas.php

Comment: Entonces puedes hacerlo de dos formas fácil, la primera es usar header en la parte de php para capturar los valores del radio y usar Location para ir a uno u otro link, la otra opción es no hacer el submit del formulario y usar un if en javascript para determinar el window.location

Comment: tienes algún ejemplo, la verdad no se javascript

Comment: Hay muchos ejemplos, sería algo así como  if(document.getElementById("seccion").value == "Encuestas") { window.location("encuestas.php"); } else { window.location("preguntas.php"); }

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Si lo que quieres es redirigir a una página en concreto según tu `radio` seleccionado, podrías hacerlo de la siguiente forma mediante `PHP`:

**Formulario**

```
<form action="votarEncuesta.php" class="contact_form" name="form1" method="post">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td width="50"><input  type="radio" id="Choice1" name="seccion" value="Encuestas"></br></td>  
            <td width="470">Encuestas</td>
        </tr> 
        <tr>
            <td width="50"><input type="radio" id="Choice2" name="seccion" value="Preguntas"></br></td>  
            <td width="470">Preguntas</td>
        </tr> 
         <tr>
            <td>
                <input type="submit" class="submit" value="Ver" />
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form>
```

**votarEncuesta.php**

```
<?php 
//Reseteo.
$seccion = '';
//Si está definido el formulario.
if (isset($_POST)) {
    //Comprobamos que no este vacío input.
    if (empty($_POST['seccion'])) {
        echo "Elige una opción. <a href='formulario.php'>Regresar</a>";
    } else {

        //Obtenemos valor input radio.
        $seccion = $_POST['seccion'] ?: '';

        //Redirigimos según opción seleccionado.
        if ($seccion == 'Encuestas') {
            echo '<script>window.location="encuesta.php"</script>';
        } else {
            echo '<script>window.location="preguntas.php"</script>';
        }
    }   
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Añado mi comentario como respuesta por si no quieres usar php para la redirección.

```
if(document.getElementById("seccion").value == "Encuestas") {
    window.location("encuestas.php");
} else {
    window.location("preguntas.php");
}
```